# Not Having any output after having added two JPanel on a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlayeredpane

What I'm trying to do is overwriting two panels, where I am Inserting an Image in the background panel through the use of a JLabel, and I want another smaller panel to appear on that same background Image! Here is what I have written:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.ImageView;

import java.awt.*;

public class addImage extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private ImageIcon Image;
    private JButton b;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JLayeredPane layerpanel;

    public addImage() {
        // JFRame
        super("First Time adding Image");
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(400, 400);

        // JLabel containing Image
        Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.jpg"));
        // Adding Image in JLabel
        label = new JLabel(Image);

        // Adding Label to panel1
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(label);

        // JPanel2
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel2.setOpaque(true);

        // LAyeredPane adding both panels
        layerpanel = new JLayeredPane();
        layerpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        layerpanel.add(panel1, new Integer(0), 0);
        layerpanel.add(panel2, new Integer(1), 1);

        add(layerpanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new addImage();

    }

}
```

After executing the piece of code Im not getting any output except the empty frame!
I am getting these errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at addImage.<init>(addImage.java:45)
    at addImage.main(addImage.java:53)
```

I have checked all the question related but still I have not been able to find the solution!!!!
Any kind of help will be appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: The exception says it occurs at line 45. Which line is that?

Comment: layerpanel.add(panel1, new Integer(0), 0);

Comment: `setLayout(null);` ... well, there's a good start

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is here:

```
layerpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
layerpanel.add(panel1, new Integer(0), 0);
layerpanel.add(panel2, new Integer(1), 1);
```

and it's not helped by

```
setLayout(null);
```

The `JLayeredPane` now requires that you pass it one of the valid constraints for `BorderLayout` (like `BorderLayout.NORTH`).

Having said that, I'm not sure what you hope to achieve doing this.

You could get the same effect by using a `CardLayout` with a lot less mess, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

I can "replicate" your desired output using something like...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AddImage extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private ImageIcon Image;
    private JButton b;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JLayeredPane layerpanel;

    public AddImage() {
        // JFRame
        super("First Time adding Image");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(400, 400);

        // JLabel containing Image
//      Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.jpg"));
        // Adding Image in JLabel
        label = new JLabel("Help");

        // Adding Label to panel1
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(label);

        // JPanel2
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel2.setOpaque(true);

        // LAyeredPane adding both panels
        layerpanel = new JLayeredPane();
        layerpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        layerpanel.add(panel1, gbc);
        layerpanel.add(panel2, gbc);

        layerpanel.setLayer(panel1, new Integer(0));
        layerpanel.setLayer(panel2, new Integer(1));

        add(layerpanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddImage();

    }

}
```